# Free SOCKS5 server

Tags: gratis, server, proxy

I'm currently using a Squid server on Windows to provide an HTTP proxy to other PCs in my internal network. With programs like ProxyCap you can force any application to use a proxy, which is pretty cool. HOWEVER, for gaming you need a SOCKS5 server capable of relaying UDP packets.

I've searched FAR and WIDE for a full SOCKS5 server but I've been unsuccessful. Do you know any server that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ssh tunnels?  The ssh client can do a dynamic socks5 proxy...

> -D [bind_address:]port - 
>     Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.
>     This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local
>     side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
>     connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
>     the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to
>     determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently
>     the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act
>     as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.
>     Dynamic port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration 
>     file.

Answer (score 0):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) has a fully-featured SOCKS server in it, and is free for 10 concurrently connected users.

The SOCKS server supports SOCKS4, SOCKS4a, SOCKS5 with UDPASSOCIATE and authentication (including Kerberos for AD integrated auth if you buy an enterprise license - not many clients support this though, I only know of 1, the OpenText client).

You also can hook policy to events (such as connect request, bind etc) to alter requests if you wish (e.g. divert connections).  You can also intercept port 80/443 to the www proxy so that http via SOCKS can benefit from caching, and web access rules (and other plugin filters such as AV).

disclaimer: I work for Qbik who is the author of WinGate.